# jQuery selector : 'starts-with && ends-with' doesnt work on element with multiple classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

The issue is simply as following, when I try to select a class that starts with a keyword , and ends with another keyword, this works fine, if and only if the element has a single class, if element has multiple classes, the selector will return an empty collection.

Here is code to explain the issue

```js
// try removing custom-class from first element --> returns 2

alert($("div[class^='start'][class*='end']").length) // will return 1 by default , only 1 element has single class.
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-class start-mid-end" data-custom="1st Div">

</div>
<div class="start-mid-end" data-custom="2nd Div">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because for the element with `class="custom-class start-mid-end"`, the value of its `class` attribute begins with `custom`, not `start`. Remember, the attribute selectors operate on the attribute value as a single string; they don't care that the `class` attribute is "special" in HTML.

Regarding a solution to your problem: there aren't any without caveats. As the most practical workaround, I would suggest using multiple classes instead of just one. For example, instead of just `prefix-X-suffix` also add the classes `prefix- -suffix` and then you can select your elements simply with

```
$("div[.prefix-.-suffix]")
```

Another option would be to use `filter` to customize the class selection logic, e.g.

```
$("div").filter(function() { return /\bstart\S*end\b/.test(this.className); })
```

The regex `\bstart\S*end\b` matches any sequence of non-whitespace characters with the prefix `start` and the suffix `end`, which is what you are after.

Comment: thanks for answer , the second answer will do , first doesn't though , sometimes you don't have much options when you are working on a really old , and complicated structure.

Answer (score 1):

The selectors you use refer to the whole attribute string, so `class="start what ever end"` will be a match.